# Capybara webkit js: true still send request as HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webkit, capybara

I have all configuration options listed on https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit

gem 'capybara-webkit'

Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit 
tests ran , and works. But not for js: true. All links and forms with remote: true are requested by HTML instead of JS, so my controller try to render new.html instead of new.js.erb f.e.

Any ideas where i should search for issue ? I found 1 issue on github, but person who requested it finally wrote: "now it works, but i don't know why" .

Comment: Please update your question with the code for your test and any relevent controller/model code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out that it was an issue with some javascript that jquery was using. It was preventing jquery-ujs from initializing. To fix the problem, I updated my jquery-rails gem.

You can view the detailed conversation of the issue here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/351